# How can I send userId from android to Unity?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am making a android application. In this app I am using firebase authentication and realtime database. I add a simple Unity game in my application. In this game I want to keep score. But don't know how to get userId from android studio and add score info in my unityGame.

Answer (score 0):

`SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` may help you. Check this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html)

Comment: I am trying to transfer userId which create from firebase realtime database in android. I don't need device' ID.